# Implementation of security in GCDAsyncSocket

Tags: gcdasyncsocket

I am trying to implement security in GCDAsyncSocket using the self signed certificate. After calling the startTLS, didReceiveTrust method is not getting called.

```
SecIdentityRef identityRef = nil;
NSArray *certs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(__bridge id)identityRef, nil];
NSMutableDictionary *settings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];

[settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0] forKey:GCDAsyncSocketSSLProtocolVersionMax];
[settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust];
[settings setObject:certs forKey:GCDAsyncSocketSSLCertificates];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where `settings` is being used.

In your call to `startTLS`, you must set `GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust` to `@YES`:

```
[self.socket startTLS:@{GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust: @YES}];
```

Relevant documentation: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/CocoaAsyncSocket/7.4.1/Classes/GCDAsyncSocket.html#//api/name/startTLS: